# C#, Google API: Авторизация по OAuth2 в Google

Tags: c#, google-oauth2

Доброго времени суток.

**Имею следующие вводные:**

1. Есть телеграм-бот, который должен обратиться к некоторым ресурсам гугла от лица какого-то юзера гугла. Ресурсы гугл просто так не выдаёт, нужна OAuth аутентификация.
2. Я сделал на стороне гугла необходимые настройки, а именно добавил OAuth Client ID и API Key. Первый делал по [этой ссылке](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials?hl=ru), второй уже самостоятельно.
3. При попытке запуска кода(пока что в простом HelloWorld проекте) с [.net quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet?hl=ru) меня выкидывает на страницу авторизации с ошибкой 400

[image: окно с ошибкой]

**Что я хочу получить?**

1. Мне нобходимо в первую очередь запустить HelloWorld проект, чтобы понять суть происходящего при логине в гугл.
2. Мне необходимо, чтобы в телеграм-боте была возможность авторизации в гугл аккаунте с доступом к тем или иным ресурсам гугла от лица какого-то конкретного пользователя.

**Что мне не понятно?**

1. какой тип credentials.json мне нужно создать? как я понял - это WebApplication для НЕ JS проектов
2. Как заставить эту штуку работать? Что я делаю не так?
3. Почему оно не работает так, как мне нужно, а ругается ошибкой на скриншоте?

P.S. Не привожу код из своего проекта, т.к. у меня не запускается банально даже простейший пример с ссылки описанной в вводных.

Comment: У вас проблемы с кодом, но кода в вопросе нет.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11485644/6808809

Comment: @tym32167 потому что я не вижу целесообразным копировать код из документации гугла

Comment: Я вам подсказал, как улучшить ваш вопрос и повысить шанс, что на него кто нибудь ответит. Следовать моему совету или нет - дело ваше.